# Updating PHP configuration through browser?

Tags: php

I'm creating my first CMS style website, and still have quite some ways to go, but I want to know:
Can I update a php configuration file through a php script?

For example:

```
<?php
$forum="1";
$about="1";
$register="0";
?>

<?php    
if ($about==("1"))
    echo '<a href="about.php">About Us</a>';
if ($forum==("1"))
    echo '<a href="forum.php">Forum</a>';
if ($register==("1"))
    echo '<a href="register.php">Register</a>;
?>
```

I want to create a script that, when I'm logged in as an admin on the site, I can update the first set to change the value of the different pages so that I can choose what displays and what doesn't.

Comment: the first thing you will need to do is to use a database, here is a good place to get started [Databases](http://devzone.zend.com/12/php-101-part-8-databases-and-other-animals_part-1/)

Answer (score 1):

To get started with a CMS you need to learn how to interact with a database. Databases are the best options if you want to be able to create an admin section and edit stuff.

Here is a link to a website that was very valuable to me when i got started

[PHP for beginners](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make use of a storage or database for this. Store the configurations somewhere editable.

Here's an example that uses file:

```
<?php
$forum = file_get_contents('forum');
$about = file_get_contents('about');
$register = file_get_contents('register');
```

You can then make an admin module that write these settings to the respective files, like so:

```
<?php 
// Admin, overwriting configurations

file_put_contents('forum', 1); // should the admin choses to enable Forum.
file_put_contents('about', 1); // should the admin choses to enable About Us.
file_put_contents('register', 0); // should the admin choses to disable Register.

//... etc for the rest of the modules
```

Comment: Appreciate it; so essentially I'm heading down the right path i just need to have more database interaction knowledge first; as of right now with php I can set it up to where I can have people adjust it manually and just progress. Either way; gives me projects to learn more on. :) Thank you much.

Comment: Yup. :) You'll need some storage to store the configurations. I gave a simple example of using file, you can use database too.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, I agree with @uzyn and @Ibu - it would be best to learn more about using a database and then use that for your configuration data.  Having said that, I offer the following for the sake of completeness.  Please note, however, that there are security issues with this approach.

I created three files:  the configuration file, named config.cfg; a PHP file to show the configuration, named show_config.php; and another PHP file, named write_config.php, to save configuration changes and then call show_config.php to re-display the configuration.  All are oversimplified and appear below.

**[config.cfg]**

```
cfg_data: 42
```

**[show_config.php]**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Configuration</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$cfg_name = "config.cfg";
$cfg_data = file_get_contents($cfg_name);
$lines = explode("\n", $cfg_data);
$cfg_vals = explode(":", $lines[0]);
$cfg_value = trim($cfg_vals[1]);
?>
<form action="write_config.php">
Configuration Value: <?php echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"config_val\" value=\"$cfg_value \" >" ?> </input>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**[write_config.php]**

```
<?php
$cfg_name = "config.cfg";
$new_data = "cfg_data: " . $_REQUEST['config_val'];
if (file_exists($cfg_name)) {
  unlink($cfg_name);
}
try {
  file_put_contents($cfg_name, $new_data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Exception caught!  " . $e -> getMessage() . "<br> \n";
}
header("Location:show_config.php");
$cfg_name = "config.cfg";
$new_data = "cfg_data: " . $_REQUEST['config_val'];
if (file_exists($cfg_name)) {
  unlink($cfg_name);
}
try {
  file_put_contents($cfg_name, $new_data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Exception caught!  " . $e -> getMessage() . "<br> \n";
}
header("Location:show_config.php");
?>
```

Note that in order for this to work, the permissions on config.cfg had to be set to o:rwx (using `> chmod o+wx config.cfg`), which is one of the security issues.  Also, this code does no input sanitizing.  If you would actually use something like this, you should check and clean all user input before you save anything.